# WooCommerce Product detail page: Add content under thumbnails

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to add content under the product feature image and its thumbnails using **action** `woocommerce_before_single_product_summary` but the content goes on the top of the image and content.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' , 'bbloomer_add_below_prod_gallery', 9 );
```

When I change the priority from 9 to 20, the right-side content moves under the custom content.

Following is the action function to render the custom content.

```php
function bbloomer_add_below_prod_gallery() {
    global $product;
        echo '<div class="text" style="border: thin solid black; clear: both;">';
        echo '<p>Random text now</p>';
        echo '</div>';
}
```

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

I tried **Woocommerce template override** also, but no luck.
When I tried to override `woocommerce/templates/sigle-product/product-image.php` in theme, the custom content still goes on the top.

Thanks

Comment: WooCommerce and other 3rd party plugin/theme dev support is off topic and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their groups and communities.

Answer (score 1):

In [`woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-templates-content-single-product.html) you can see that `woocommerce_show_product_images` is hoooked with a priority of 20.

if you want your custom function to render below the images, but above the summary, you need to set the priority to greater than 20. I think the code below should do it:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_add_below_prod_gallery', 30);

function bbloomer_add_below_prod_gallery() {
    global $product;
    echo '<div class="text" style="border: thin solid black; clear: both;">';
    echo '<p>Random text now</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

**UPDATE**

The default woocommerce stylesheet [woocommerce-layout.scss](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/37205ff4e0f489f28345895b12a0d5d602b0af4d/assets/css/woocommerce-layout.scss#L57)  floats the gallery to the left and gives it 48% width, like this:

```css
.woocommerce #content div.product div.images, .woocommerce div.product div.images, .woocommerce-page #content div.product div.images, .woocommerce-page div.product div.images {
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
}
```

You could add this style to your html, but depending on the theme you are using, it might end up to the right of the gallery (because it is floated).

So, the quickest thing, if you want to get your text directly underneath the gallery element, would be to override the [`product-image.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/37205ff4e0f489f28345895b12a0d5d602b0af4d/templates/single-product/product-image.php) template and add an extra hook.

```html
// In your copy of product-image.php everything is the same except the new action hook.
...
<div class="...">
    <figure class="woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper">
        <?php
        // Stuff copied from original template.
        ...
        do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' );
        ?>
    </figure>

    <!-- Create a new action hook before the final <div> -->
    <?php do_action( 'bbloomer_after_single_product_gallery' ); ?>
</div>
...
```

Then hook in to this new action in your theme.

```php
add_action('bbloomer_after_single_product_gallery', 'bbloomer_add_below_prod_gallery', 30);

function bbloomer_add_below_prod_gallery() {
    global $product;
    echo '<div class="text" style="border: thin solid black; clear: both;">';
    echo '<p>Random text now</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Or just add the html directly in your new template instead of adding a hook.

Comment: I tried it with priority 30. Yes It adds the content undere images but the issue is, that custom content goes as a row accross the left and right column and moves the right column content down.

https://easyupload.io/zrl1sx

Comment: Ah, I understand.

Comment: I've updated my solution for you.